# How to find $f(m)=\prod\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^m}\right)^{-1}$ (if $m>1$)?

Tags: riemann-zeta, infinite-product

First case $m=2$ is pretty simple:
$$\prod\limits_{n=2}^{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-1}=\frac{2k}{k+1}$$
Of course $k>1$ and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(2)=2$.

How to find $f(m)$ for other cases?

Comment: From [*The Probability Lifesaver*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=EWd9DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA543&lpg=PA543&dq=when+you+see+a+product+you+should+seriously+consider+changing+it+to+a+sum&source=bl&ots=mlWhPTme2X&sig=1IUVxCCIqHXyH7f76GGlNU040CM&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9zOHzidXYAhVE_qQKHbG3ApsQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=when%20you%20see%20a%20product%20you%20should%20seriously%20consider%20changing%20it%20to%20a%20sum&f=false): "whenever you see a product, you should *seriously* consider replacing it with a sum".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Infinite_product_formulae) and rework a little bit the formulae for $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$, you could find that, if
$$p_m=\prod\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^m}\right)^{-1}$$
$$p_3= 3\pi \, \text{sech}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}\right)$$
$$p_4=4 \pi\,  \text{csch}(\pi )$$ For $m>4$, I imagine that this would be given by some ugly gamma functions.

Using a CAS, I found that
$$p_6=6 \pi ^2 \,\text{sech}^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}\right)$$

Comment: Your particular results agree with my answer. In particular, I was useful to me because I check my answer against your results.

Comment: @FelixMarin. I found a typo for $p_3$ (a multiplying factor of $3$ was missing.

Comment: Don't worry. I was aware of that. In particular, $\texttt{Mathematica}$ is not friendly enough with $p_{3}$ (it uses something like $\left(-1\right)^{2/3}$). I just checked $p_{2}, p_{4}, p_{6},\ldots$ and everything is fine. It agrees too with $\texttt{@Olivier Oloa}$ answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. By recalling the [Weierstrass infinite product of the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions),
$$
\Gamma(1+z) = e^{-\gamma z} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+ \frac z n \right)^{-1} e^{z/n},\qquad \text{Re}z>-1, \tag1
$$ then, by writing each factor of the given product over the complex numbers using roots of unity,
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{n^m}\right)^{-1}=\prod_{k=1}^{m}\left(1-\frac{e^{2ik\pi/m}}{n}\right)^{-1},\qquad n\ge2, \tag2
$$ one gets

> $$
> f(m)=\prod\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^m}\right)^{-1}=\prod_{k=1}^{m}\Gamma\left(2-e^{2ik\pi/m}\right) \tag3
> $$

from which many particular cases are deduced.

Comment: Thank you for answer! It looks like we can solve most of math problems using only gamma function.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{N \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 2}}$ and $\ds{\omega_{k} = \exp\pars{2k\pi\ic/m}}$:

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\left.\prod_{n = 2}^{N}\pars{1 - {1 \over n^{m}}}^{-1}\,\right\vert_{\ m\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 2}}}} =
\prod_{n = 2}^{N}{n^{m} \over n^{m} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{N!}^{m}\prod_{n = 2}^{N}
{1 \over \pars{n - \omega_{1}}\cdots
\pars{n - \omega_{m}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{N!}^{m}\prod_{k = 1}^{m}{1 \over \pars{2 - \omega_{k}}^{\overline{N - 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{N!}^{m}\prod_{k = 1}^{m}{\Gamma\pars{2 - \omega_{k}} \over
\Gamma\pars{N + 1 - \omega_{k}}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&
\bracks{\prod_{k = 1}^{m}\Gamma\pars{2 - \omega_{k}}}
\prod_{k = 1}^{m}{\root{2\pi}N^{N + 1/2}\expo{-N} \over
\root{2\pi}\pars{N - \omega_{k}}^{N - \omega_{k} + 1/2}
\expo{-\pars{N -\omega_{k}}}}
\\[5mm] = &
\bracks{\prod_{k = 1}^{m}\Gamma\pars{2 - \omega_{k}}}
\prod_{k = 1}^{m}\bracks{{N^{N + 1/2} \over
N^{N - \omega_{k} + 1/2}}
\,{\expo{-\omega_{k}} \over \pars{1 - \omega_{k}/N}^{N - \omega_{k} + 1/2}}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\, &
\bracks{\prod_{k = 1}^{m}\Gamma\pars{2 - \omega_{k}}}
\prod_{k = 1}^{m}N^{\omega_{k}} =
\bracks{\prod_{k = 1}^{m}\Gamma\pars{2 - \omega_{k}}}
N^{\sum_{k = 1}^{m}\omega_{k}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\to} &\
\bbx{\prod_{k = 1}^{m}\Gamma\pars{2 - \exp\pars{2\pi k\ic \over m}}}
\\[2mm] &\
\pars{\begin{array}{l}
\mbox{Note that}\ m = 2\ yields\ \Gamma\pars{3}\Gamma\pars{1} = \color{red}{2}
\\
\mbox{which is the OP particular example.}
\\[3mm]
\mbox{In addition, it agrees with the particular}
\\
\mbox{values of}\ \color{#66f}{\texttt{@Claude Leibovici}}\ \mbox{answer.}
\end{array}}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{m}\omega_{k} =
> \sum_{k = 1}^{m}\exp\pars{2\pi k\ic \over m} = \color{red}{0}}$.

Answer (score 2):

We may also notice that
$$ \prod_{n\geq 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^m}\right)^{-1} = \exp\sum_{n\geq 2}-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^m}\right)=\exp\sum_{n\geq 2}\sum_{h\geq 1}\frac{1}{h n^{mh}} $$
equals
$$ \exp\left[m\sum_{h\geq 1}\frac{\zeta(mh)-1}{mh}\right]=\exp\left[m\sum_{h\geq 1}\frac{1}{(mh)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{mh-1}}{e^{x}-1}\,dx\right] $$
and for integer values of $m\geq 2$ we may deduce a closed form by applying the discrete Fourier transform to the Taylor series of the exponential function, then by invoking the residue theorem.