# Value of $\prod_{n>1} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n^s}}$ or $-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \log(1-\frac{1}{n^s} )$

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence, products, zeta-functions

I know

\begin{align}
\prod_{p~is~ prime} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^2}} = \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}
which has a convergent number.

actually I can even generalized this to

\begin{align}
\prod_{p ~is~ prime} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^s}} = \zeta(s)  
\end{align}
For $s>1$ [consider $s\in \mathbb{R}$] we know zeta function converges, so this   has a convergent number.

How about generalization to arbitrary integers? [i.e., I want to replace $p$ with arbitrary integer $n$.]

For example $s=2$, we have

\begin{align}
 \prod_{n>1} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}
\end{align}

taking log we need to show 
\begin{align}
- \sum_{n=2} \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2} \right) 
\end{align}
 is convergent or not.

simply by telescope method I can see this value converges to $\log(2)$, that means $ \prod_{n>1} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}} = 2$.

Now consider $s>1$.

\begin{align}
-\sum_{n>1} \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^s}\right)
\end{align}
This is convergent from comparison test.

Simply take $a_n = -\log(1-\frac{1}{n^s})$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n^s}$, then 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{-\log(1-x)}{x} = 1 >0
\end{align}
and since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n = \zeta(s)$ is convergent for $s>1$, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n$ also converges.

What I want to obtain is the value of such convergent series, first i tried telescope method, but it seems difficult even for $s=3$.

Is there a way to compute exact value of those products?

How and what is the values of those products?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned no closed form formula is known for $s>2$. By the way, when $s=2$ the product equals $2$, not $1/2$.

Comment: @Klangen, thanks, I found typos and corrected it! $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \log(1-\frac{1}{n^2} ) = - \log(2)$. 

I am quite surprised that for $s>2$, no closed form formula is known!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2603561

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $2k\ge 2$ $$\prod_{n=2}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{n^{2k}})=\prod_{m=1}^{2k} \prod_{n=2}^\infty (1-\frac{e^{2i \pi m/(2k)}}{n}) = \prod_{m=1}^{k}\prod_{n =-\infty, |n|\ge 2}^\infty (1-\frac{e^{2i \pi m/(2k)}}{n}) = \prod_{m=1}^{k} f(e^{2i \pi m/(2k)})$$ 
[where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Examples_of_factorization) $f(x)  =\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x(1-x^2)} $ and in those products the order of summation is meant to be $\lim_{N \to \infty} \prod_{|n| \le N} $

For $k \ge 2$  $$\prod_{n=2}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{n^k})=\prod_{m=1}^kg(e^{2i \pi m/k}), \qquad g(x)  =\frac{1}{(-x)(1-x)\Gamma(-x)}= \frac{1}{\Gamma(2-x)}$$

Comment: what is $g(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(-x)(-x)(1-x)}$?, you mean $\Gamma(-x)\Gamma(-x)\Gamma(1-x)$?

Comment: @phy_math: he means $\;g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x(x-1)\Gamma(-x)}\;$ which returns the correct result (notice that he is computing the multiplicative inverse of your formula).

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni Thanks! I got it

Answer (score 5):

Let 
$$P_s=\prod_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1-n^{-s}}$$

Using a CAS, there are some nice expressions such as
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
s & P_s \\
 2 & 2 \\
 3 & 3 \pi  \text{sech}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}\right) \\
 4 & 4 \pi  \text{csch}(\pi ) \\
 6 & 6 \pi ^2 \text{sech}^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}\right) 
\end{array}
\right)$$
$P_5$ and the other ones are quite ugly.

Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+1%2F(1-1%2Fn%5E3)+from+n%3D2+to+infinity).